# calculate elapsed time in oracle between entries from one particular condition to whatever condition is next

Tags: oracle

Im trying to calculate machine run time.  I have an oracle database being populated with an entry every time the machines status changes. Im basically entering the time and the status type. status type 1 = machine running.  there are a number of other status types depending on the condition of the machine so after a type 1 is logged the next event could be any number of status types.  so what im looking for is something like:

```
SELECT (DATE_DT **<where status type =1>**  - LEAD(DATE_DT **<where status type is any - whatever is next>**) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_DT DESC)) AS EVENT_DURATION
```

here is the actual code ive tried but it returns the elapsed time from when a cycle started until when the next cycle started instead of from when the cycle started to whatever the next event was for example in most cases the next status after #1 machine running is #0 machine idle (but its not always idle could be other status types.)

```
SELECT to_char((EVENT_DURATION) + trunc(sysdate), 'HH24:MI:SS')  FROM 
(SELECT (DATE_DT - LEAD(DATE_DT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_DT DESC)) AS EVENT_DURATION
FROM TEST_CHRIS 
WHERE ASSET_ID = 4380 
AND EVENTTYPE = 1
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the filtering in the outer query, after doing the `lead()`:

```
SELECT to_char((EVENT_DURATION) + trunc(sysdate), 'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM (SELECT (DATE_DT - LEAD(DATE_DT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_DT DESC)) AS EVENT_DURATION
      FROM TEST_CHRIS
     ) tc
WHERE ASSET_ID = 4380 AND EVENTTYPE = 1 AND
      trunc(DATE_DT) = trunc(SYSDATE);
```

I'm not sure if the other conditions on `ASSET_ID` and `DATE_DT` should be in the subquery or the outer query.

Comment: awesome, thank you!!! I wasnt looking at it the right way.  that worked just had to add "eventtype" to the inner query with the same lead function.